# How to decrypt the password,which was encrypted by salt in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to **decrypt** the password,which was encrypted by salt in php?

Comment: You can't, and **that's the whole point**. It's not *encrypted*, it's *hashed*.

Comment: You simply don't, because if you could, it wouldn't make sense to hash a password if you could just reformat it into the old password. The only chance you have is guessing what the salt is, remove it and try to cause a collision, but well, have fun doing that.

Comment: You can't reverse salt beef to recreate the cow

Answer (score 2):

You cannot decrypt the password, if you really want to find out for yourself search some more over the internet for 'Salt Decrypters' or whatever but it will be pointless

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

In cryptography, a salt is random data that is used as an additional input to a **one-way function** that hashes a password or passphrase.

A salt makes the hash computation unique so that adversaries wishing to break passwords cannot make computations that are useful to break many passwords at once.

You cannot recover the password from the hash. With a proper password hash, the only way to recover the password given the hash is to make a guess and verify it.

---

References:

- [Decrypting the password from SHA-512 hash value](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10908/decrypting-the-password-from-sha-512-hash-value)
- [Decrypting password after a password hash encrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508906/decrypting-password-after-a-password-hash-encrypt)
- [Cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)

Answer (score 0):

The point of hashing is that you won't try to find the origin cleartext password but if you need a login system for example, you will compare the one stored in database (which is hashed) with the one that your user has provided which you'll hash.